# How to add data in env.php(app/etc/env.php) file from controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration

I need to set some data to the env.php file from my controller.Is there any possible way to do so.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to add ? Any reason why it has to be this file in particular ?

Comment: I was trying to add some data like server, port etc to the env file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Writer class is responsible for write deployment configuration. You can ask it in the constructor of your controller and then save data.

Example code:

```
<?php

class MyAction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Writer $deploymentConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->deploymentConfig = $deploymentConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo $this->deploymentConfig->saveConfig([ConfigFilePool::APP_ENV => ['your_key' => $data]]);
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how can we write data to the env file programmatically

Comment: I update Answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.It was really helpful for me..!

Comment: To use saveConfig() func we need to inject Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Writer;

Comment: eg :-$this->writer->saveConfig([ConfigFilePool::APP_ENV => ['your_key' => $data]]);

Comment: Thx for answer, with some minor misses: 
- _saveConfig_ must be in a try catch with _\Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException_, 
- you forgot _use Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool;_ 
- and declare $deploymentConfig in your class !

Anyway, thx a lot !

Comment: Is this custom controller?When will this controller run?